Alphanumeric inputs in my independent feature- error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01232COM002-222'
I have 2 columns, one is independent which signifies PART_NO and other is dependent which is QUANTITY.
I am trying to predict the quantity of a particular machinery on the basis of which machinery it is. Now the problem is my PART_NO has alphanumeric characters like 01232COM002-222, ABCD/235, GS.612.90-19, 123456.
When I am fitting the model using RandomForestRegressor, I am getting

error: could not convert string to float,

I cannot replace any slash or comma with anything as PART_NO is unique.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

file = 'testData.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df.head()

print(f"Number of rows = {df.shape[0]}")
print(f"Number of columns = {df.shape[1]}")

print("Data types of columns: \n", df.dtypes)

print("X-Features and y-Labels")
X = df[['PART_NO']]
y = df['QUANTITY']
print("X-Features\n")
print(X.head())
print("")
print("y-Labels")
print(y.head())


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
print("Training size = ", X_train.shape)
print("Testing size = ", X_test.shape)
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

I tried LabelEncoding, OneHotEncoding, did not work, I tried string replace, did not work.

Take the sufficiently large hash of the part id and use it's bits.

What is the point of cluttering your posts with all these print statements without showing their output? Please see how to create a [mre] (emphasis on minimal).

it seem to me that you need to map your alphanumeric characters to uniques floats, the easiest way to do that seem to be converting the alphanumeric values to binary using either ascii of utf-8 encoding, then into base 10 numbers.
If you have duplicates, just stay in base 2, 0 and 1's can make a float and you're sure it's unique
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-binary/ for ways of turning a string to binary
another way, would be to simply generate a dict with the alphanumeric entries
as keys and arbitrarily distributed numbers as value, like so :
numbers = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    numbers[x[i]] = i

or in a shorter way:
numbers = {x[i]:i for i in range(len(x))}


those are float, not int but that should pose no issue
